# SilverLight: Call Child Control Event from base file

Tags: silverlight

1) BaseFile 
 
   File Contains KeyDown Event that called when any key press.

```
    private void MODULE_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
          //Here Need to Check Key press is (CTRL + ALT + S)
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == (ModifierKeys.Alt | ModifierKeys.Control) && e.Key == Key.S)
        {
            var objMBox = new ITSUI.MBox("Do you want to save records?", "Confirm", MBoxButtons.YesNo);
            objMBox.Closed += delegate
            {
                if (objMBox.m_Return == MBoxReturn.Yes)
                {
                  **Here Need to call Detail Child Control OnOk Event**                
                }
            };
            objMBox.Show();
        }
    }
```

2) Detail Child Control

```
    public void OnOk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          //Save Record Code Here
    }
```

How to call OnOk Event of Child Control from Base File?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call a child control's method from your code-behind you can set a name to the control in your view and just use its name.

```
<UserControl class="MyView">
    ...
    <MyChildControl x:Name="RecordEditView"/>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

and in your code-behind:

```
public class MyView : UserControl {
  public MyView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyDown += OnMyViewKeyDown;
  }

  private void OnMyViewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    RecordEditView.SaveRecordData();
  }
}
public class MyChildControl : UserControl
{
    public void SaveRecordData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```